actions.dart:102:13: Error: No named parameter with the name 'primary'. (ALREADY ANSWERED)

I was having an issue with my Flutter app not compiling and getting that error. Took me a while to figure out that the path mentions slidable, which is something that was added in the tutorial I was following.
When adding this dependency in pubspec.yaml. I just wrote down the same version as the tutorial => flutter_slidable: ^1.2.0. After a quick search, I found that the most recent is 3.1.0 which would explain why there would be issues.
To sum it up, check what changed between when the app worked and when it stopped working, and read the path mentioned carefully, it can just be an out-of-date dependency.
Just wanted to post this since I couldn't find this particular solution online.

As mentioned in the post, the solution is to check the version of your dependencies and make sure they aren't too old. Affected dependency is likely mentioned in the error message, read slowly.

tried using with the verion flutter_slidable: 3.1.0. solved the issue. Thanks Felix Knight
